# Why Elixir's Enum.any? slow?

Tags: profiling, elixir

I ran below command

```
MIX_ENV=prod  mix profile.fprof --no-start -e "Math.prime_seq 501"
```

for the following code

```
  def prime_seq(n) do
    prime_seq(n, 1, 3, [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23])
  end

  def prime_seq(n, c, p, cache) when c < n do
    is_it = cache |> Enum.any?(fn n -> rem(p, n) == 0 end)
    if not is_it do
      prime_seq(n, c+1, p+2, cache ++ [p])
    else
      if(is_prime(p)) do
        prime_seq(n, c+1, p+2, cache ++ [p])
      else
        prime_seq(n, c, p+2, cache)
      end
    end
  end

  def prime_seq(n, c, p, _) when c == n do
    p-2
  end
```

With result:

[image: profile result]

Why `Enum.do_any?` is taking too much time?

Yes, **this is a dumb algorithm** to find the n-th prime number and there are better algorithms. But the point is, what makes `Enum.any?` is slower than using a specialized function to iterate through the list.

I believe the anom func is `rem(p,n)`, CMIIW

**Update:**
I removed the `Enum.any?` with mine, called `divisible?`

```
 def divisible?(n, [h|t]) do
    if rem(n, h) == 0 do
      true
    else
      divisible?(n, t)
    end
  end

  def divisible?(n, []) do
    false
  end
  ..... 
  def prime_seq(n, c, p, cache) when c < n do
    #is_it = cache |> Enum.any?(fn n -> rem(p, n) == 0 end)
    is_it = divisible?(p, cache)
    if not is_it do
      prime_seq(n, c+1, p+2, cache ++ [p])
    else
      if(is_prime(p)) do
        prime_seq(n, c+1, p+2, cache ++ [p])
      else
        prime_seq(n, c, p+2, cache)
      end
    end
  end
  .....
```

result:

[image: faster]

So.. with a simple modification I can make it 3x faster and the iteration count is the same.

Note: It's a toy project while I learning elixir. Please bear with me.

is_prime function:

```
def is_prime(n, i) when i < n do
    if rem(n, i) == 0 do
      false
    else
      is_prime(n, i+1)
    end
  end
  def is_prime(n, i) when i >= n do
    true
  end
  def is_prime(n) do
    cond do
    n <= 1 -> false
    n <= 3 -> true
    rem(n, 2) == 0 or rem(n, 3) == 0 -> false
    true -> is_prime(n, 3)
    end
  end
```

Comment: Naive attempt?  Sounds suspiciously like premature optimization to me.

Comment: please check my update, thanks

Comment: So... either I'm doing premature optimization, or... `Enum.do_any?` is really slow.

Comment: When you create and profile toy code it's hard not to think of that as "premature optimization"  It seems as if you're looking for some sort of generic answer about which code is better (better being faster in this case)  but in actual practice execution speed is only rarely the primary concern.  I  mean if your code must be fast write it in assembly,  right?

Comment: yeah.. I'm still learning Elixir, and wondering why that part looks weird in profiler

Comment: Ok I  can see that I misinterpreted the nature of your question.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer question of  why `Enum.do_any?` is slower than `divisible?` I created a simple test cases for non profiled version of:

1. `cache |> Enum.any?(fn n -> rem(p, n) == 0 end)`
2. `divisible?(p, cache)`
3. `divisible_anon?(cache, fn n -> rem(p, n) == 0 end)`

The test code is:

```
 def divisible_anon?([h|t], fun) do
    if fun.(h) do
      true
    else
      divisible_anon?(t, fun)
    end
  end

  def divisible_anon?([], _) do
    false
  end

  def divisible?(n, [h|t]) do
    if rem(n, h) == 0 do
      true
    else
      divisible?(n, t)
    end
  end

  def divisible?(n, []) do
    false
  end
```

Measure with:

```
  def measure(function) do
    function
    |> :timer.tc
    |> elem(0)
    |> Kernel./(1_000_000)
  end
```

Results for `Math.prime_seq 501`:

1. 0.009852 s
2. 0.008797 s
3. 0.012836 s

Results for `Math.prime_seq 10001`:

1. 2.686799 s
2. 1.395422 s
3. 2.687937 s

**Conclusion**, with help of @sasajuric: *"Anonymous function call is expensive"*

Comment: I would not draw that conclusion. The problem is that the rest of the code is doing almost nothing. So when the cost of something is effectively zero, anything looks big compared to zero.

Comment: @FredtheMagicWonderDog could you help me draw the conclusion? so.. I know what to avoid. But in my case I still cant blame other than the expensive anon func

Comment: I agree with @FredtheMagicWonderDog Anonymous function calls are a bit slower, but as said, I think the problem here is of algorithmic nature. It would be wrong to draw a general conclusion here, because people might avoid lambdas needlessly. I'd say in almost all cases, lambda invocation is not a real performance problem.

Answer (score 5):

Since I've been asked, I'll put this as an answer rather than a comment.

The problem is not that anonymous functions are "expensive", but that the code is doing almost nothing but iterating over a list.

The BEAM scheduler uses reductions to do it's function slicing. It's slightly more complicated that this, but every function call counts as one reduction. When you use an anonymous function, you are increasing the time cost of a reduction (i.e. a lookup to the actual function is added to the time cost of 
the reduction.) Normally this extra cost is negligible, but when you do it
millions of times, it adds up.

The BEAM scheduler gives each process 2000 reductions and then time slices in
a new process.

You've created a pathological edge case that compares the value zero with another value. It doesn't matter how big or small the value is in absolute scale, if you're comparing zero with anything it looks "expensive".

The right conclusion is that recursive algorithms that scale faster than O(n) are extremely sensitive to the amount of work done in each recursion. You should be amazed that this works at all, not that it is slow.

If I get time today, I'll try and get some reduction counts for the various cases using :erlang.statistics(:exact_reductions).

I used this code to get some basic metrics.

```
defmodule Counter do

 def count(function,arg) do
  {_ , count } = :erlang.process_info(self,:reductions)
  function.(arg)
  {_ , new_count } = :erlang.process_info(self,:reductions)
  new_count - count
 end

end
```

The way this code counts reductions isn't perfect, it should really run in it's
own process.

These are the results I got, first with the Enum.any? version.

```
iex(4)> Counter.count(&Math.prime_seq/1, 10)
283
iex(5)> Counter.count(&Math.prime_seq/1, 100)
14086
iex(6)> Counter.count(&Math.prime_seq/1, 1000)
1105114
iex(7)> Counter.count(&Math.prime_seq/1, 10000)
103654258
iex(8)> Counter.count(&Math.prime_seq/1, 100000)
10068833898
```

Note all of these reductions occur in a single scheduling thread, my 8 core laptop was hardly busy at all during this test. It's obvious this is an O(n**2) algorithm in reductions. Now with the divisible function

```
iex(1)> Counter.count(&Math.prime_seq_div/1, 10)
283
iex(2)> Counter.count(&Math.prime_seq_div/1, 100)
14062
iex(3)> Counter.count(&Math.prime_seq_div/1, 1000)
1105485
iex(4)> Counter.count(&Math.prime_seq_div/1, 10000)
103655170
iex(5)> Counter.count(&Math.prime_seq_div/1, 100000)
10068870615
```

To be honest, I expected these numbers to be smaller. The fact that they aren't leads me to an alternate conclusion about what is going on, it's not more reductions, but more time per reduction.

Comment: Please, give me a portion of your spare time. I (we) want to know more :)

Comment: Where's your is_prime function? I can't run the test w/o that function. Can you add it to the code sample?

Comment: added in the bottom of question

Comment: Thanks, but as you said, your conclusion contradicts your assumption. Which mean the data is.. meaningless and make it unsuitable as the answer of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [source code of `Enum.do_any?`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/enum.ex#L2401-L2411), we can see that all it does is iterating through the list and invoking the provided lambda.

The profiling result seems to indicate that most of the time is spent outside of lambda, i.e. on iteration, which puzzles me to some extent.

Regardless, the interpretation of these results is that most of the time is spent in this line:

```
is_it = cache |> Enum.any?(fn n -> rem(p, n) == 0 end)
```

Another useful piece of information is that the code does 135k iterations for the input size of 501. That's a pretty good indication that the algorithmic complexity is at least polynomial.

Based on this, I suggest considering some algorithmic change, for example sieve of Eratosthenes. Unfortunately, I can't figure out what this code is suppose to return, so I can't provide an alternative solution.

Comment: Yes, it's a naive attempt and I also aware of better algorithm. But the point is, what's wrong in my code so that Enum.any? is that slow.

Comment: @ardhitama Keep in mind that fprof skews the results due to instrumentation overhead. If you run this without fprof, it will run much faster. Of course, it will slow down for some larger `n`. So I'd say that the only thing wrong with your code is the algorithm :-D And fprof clearly indicates that, by showing that you're doing a lot of iterations for a pretty small input size.

Comment: @ardhitama That's interesting. The difference between your code and `Enum.any?` is that you're invoking `rem` directly (rather than invoking a lambda), so that may be the reason, especially since `rem` is a BIF (IIRC), which would mean that it is not profiled. You could add lambda as a parameter there and see if you get similar results. Finally, keep in mind that profiling distorts running times. The times you see there can be higher than the actual times you'll get when you run without profiling. In other words, I'm not certain that your optimization really affects non profiled execution.

Comment: Sadly, it does affect the non profiled execution. Though... when my `divisible?` is turned to accept the lambda, the profiler said the same result as `Enum.any?`

Comment: That might be due to the cost of the lambda invocation then. You are doing 135k lambda calls for the input size 500. I still think you should consider algorithmic optimization, which might bring significant improvements.

Comment: Well, Enum.any? is doing almost exactly the same thing your divisible function does, but with two extra levels of indirection. There is no free lunch, and in this case the algorithm is completely dependent on how fast you can iterate over the list.

Comment: @ardhitama Are you trying to compute the nth prime? If so, I had a lazy prime generator lying somewhere on the disk. Based on it I made a naive implementation of nth prime. This is surely not optimal, and is also not very well tested. On my machine, it takes 0.3 sec to get 10000th prime, and about 5 sec for the 100000th prime. It normally uses lambdas, Enum, and Stream. The code can be found at http://gist.github.com/sasa1977/fcf245c23e2498e4e985 It's just an example of how algorithmic change can improve things. There's probably a better algorithm for this, but I didn't research deeper.

Answer (score 0):

If you need extreme performance, Elixir/Erlang might not be the right tool. The Erlang VM performance is not great for CPU-bound tasks. Instead you might want to call out to a highly optimized external library such as [primesieve](https://github.com/kimwalisch/primesieve/). You can learn how to write a so-called port in order to call native code in [this recent Elixir Sips episode](http://elixirsips.com/episodes/194_interoperability_ports.html) (free).

Comment: Yes, I aware the there are faster options. But this is just a toy project, and `Enum.any?` is slower than my simple `divisible?` . (Please check my update)

Answer (score 0):

`Enum.any?` is implemented by relying on the Enumerable (using reducees): http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/05/introducing-reducees/

Generalization is the opposite of specialization. So while we can work with any data type, it won't be as fast as if you implement the list variant yourself. However, this doesn't mean we are bound to be slower, we can easily inline those operations in Enum, reducing the cost altogether.

Comment: So, it's not because of anonymous function? Have you checked my answer?